# I can't find my Wi-Fi settings on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04

I can't find my Wi-Fi settings on Ubuntu 18.04. After turning it on today, I cannot use the internet.

Even if I plug an RG45 cable in, the internet is not working.

Here is an image of my screen:

[image: shoot of my screen]

What are your suggestions?

Comment: Boot with a previous kernel using grub menu. Network should work. Then add output of `dpkg -l | grep linux` to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 thank you please do you have any example im not very experienced in ubunto or explaine with more détails step by step thank you again im stack since yesterday

Comment: You should get int grub menu on boot and select another kernel there.

Comment: @Pilot 6 its look like `ubunto /  Advanced options for ubunto /Memory test `

Comment: It is in Advanced options. Select some previous kernel there.

Comment: i tried to select a recovery mode and followed the steps and i reboot but still nothing change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116276/discussion-between-younes-oulkaid-and-pilot6).